# Plotting several sequences of frames from tiff files with a chosen size

Tags: image, matlab, plot, tiff, matlab-figure

I am analyzing some experimental data in the form of .tiff multi frames. Withins these tiff files i need to visualize and compare some specific sequences of frames. I want to generate a figure that contains the frames i have chosen from the files i have chosen. The file list and frames indexes list are generated with a user interface, which calls a plot function when parameters are filled.

The problem : What is the best solution so as to plot, with an optimal size BUT keeping square images (like the original), the chosen frames ? Simpler, how to choose the position and size of each frame i plot in the figure ?

I have tried with sub plot : it works but I can't manage to control the images size.

```
pos=0;
for j = 1:length(file_list)
    for i = 1:length(index_list)
         pos=pos+1;
         subplot(size(file_list,1),length(index_list),pos)
         a =imagesc(imread(file_list{j,:},index_list(i)));
```

I have also tried

```
for j = 1:length(file_list)
    for i = 1:length(index_list)
         a =imagesc(imread(file_list{j,:},index_list(i))); 
         set(gca,'Units','Pixels', 'Position', [10+100*i 10+100*j 100 100]);
```

But it seems like i can't set this individually without overwriting the last modification.

Finally, i have considered using "montage", but the way I save the images in a list doesn't seem to be ok.

```
    frm_list=zeros(1,length(FL)*length(index_list));
for j = 1:length(FL)
    for i = 1:length(index_list)
        a =(imread(FL{j,:},index_list(i)));
        frm_list=[frm_list a];
    end
end

montage(frm_list,'Size', [length(FL) length(index_list)]);
```

Thanks
JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `axis image` to keep the same aspect ratio of the original image.

`subplot('Position', [left bottom width height])` allows you to specify the relative position of the image to the figure window.

If you want to use a command other than `imagesc`, you can scale the data range of the image before drawing , then use `colormap` to apply false coloring to the image.

Comment: Thanks @rwong . Using it just like that : 

`scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize'); 
plt=figure(); 
set(plt,'Position',scrsz); 
for j = 1:length(FL) 
   for i = 1:length(index_list) 
   subplot('Position', [10*i+50*i 10*j+50*j 50 50])   
   imagesc(imread(FL{j,:},index_list(i)));`

Returns an empty figure, while using the subplot command as like as I wrote in the previous post give me the right figure (but with an automatic size that doesn't suit to my needs). I can't understand why. It should add an image to a relevant place according to the number of times the loop has been used.

Comment: Well, sorry for the hardly-readable code in the previous post, I do not know how to make it better in the "add comment" window. 
`axis square` gave a good result, but do not allow me to chose the space between two rows in the subplot. Thank you again, I'll deal with this axis square solution.